# Fastest data structure for inserting billions of integers?

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, quicksort, abstract-data-type

I want recommendation on which is the fastest data structure in C which can hold about 2 billion integers taken from input. The integer value would not be less than 0 and would not be greater than 2 billion. My goal is to remove any duplicate values and sort elements of the data structure. If possible, I want to able to do the inserting operation in *O(1)* or *O(logn)* or as quickly as possible. I also want to avoid trees if possible. I would appreciate any feedback or recommendation about this.

Edit: Using a normal array would take a really long time. So, I want to use some other data structure than the array such as stack, queue, etc.

Comment: Array is the fastest for direct access. Removing duplicates and sorting is another story, but you haven't specified any requirements about it.

Comment: Agreed. Pre-allocate the memory, and use an array if speed of insertion is your primary concern. Once they're inserted, quicksort them (O(n log n)), and copy into preallocated storage while removing duplicates (O(n)). (I see I've exactly repeated @dbush's answer from the deleted question.)

Comment: Consider a bit map: Create an array of 2,000,000,001 bits (such as an array of 62,500,001 `uint32_t` elements). Initialize it to zero. As each integer is read, maps its value v to the bit indexed v in the array. Set that bit. This automatically removes duplicates, as each bit merely indicates a value has been seen at least once. To produce the sorted results, simply traverse the array in order and report each set bit. If the values are somewhat uniformly distributed, this may be the best solution. Insertion is O(1), reporting is O(n). If they are somehow clustered, improvement may be possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is fastest, but one way for sorting is 1. allocate an array with 2 billion + 1 elements 2. initialize that to all zero 3. count occurrences of each integers using the array 4. Extract the indice (originally the integers to hold) with positive occurrences.

Comment: Any alternatives to the array? Such as stack, queue, priority queue, etc?

Comment: Yes, there are many alternatives to an array. Nothing in your questions suggests they would be good for you. Why do you want one?

Comment: (Note the n in the O(n) in the reporting complexity is the number of potential values, 2,000,000,001. So it is fixed as the problem is actually stated, technically O(1) in that regard. Presumably, though, we are concerned with the fact we must traverse the array that is n bits in size, not the fact that the array is fixed in size as the problem is stated.)

Comment: @SamuelJakes you should fully specify your operations including the required complexities. Then you can simply browse the well-known data structures to find the one which is answering your requirements. If you can't find one, then you can try to come up with a combination of them. Then, if unsuccessful you can ask other to suggest something. Note that any data structure might have a significant memory overhead, so 2 billion integers will consume 2*X billions of bytes in memory where `X` depends on the data structure of choice.

Comment: (Eric; deleted my comment. You're right. The giant bitfield is an excellent design.)

Comment: Why do you think using an array would be slower that a different data structure?

Comment: If duplicates are rare, cheap insertion is key and you will be keeping almost all the numbers, so store in an array, then sort. If duplicates are frequent, you should dedupe as you go, a structure that remains sorted is helpful, you may have to overcome your dislike of trees...

Comment: I am not sure but I think traversing through an array which has billions of integers would be really long. I want to remove duplicate values in the data structure than sort them, so I think it would take a longer time, overall.

Comment: FYI, stacks and queues are typically implemented as arrays.

Comment: I dont want to use a tree, since I would run out of RAM if the all the integers are unique.

Comment: Since the values are coming from input, they are probably coming one by one. So you can *insert* them into an already sorted data structure when checking if it is duplicated. So each insertion will be O(log N) - for binary search for sorted insertion, then no other operations are even required. A catch that for arrays it is tricky as each insertion will require "shifting" part of the array. But it is easy with linked list, which will be more memory expensive. So you really need to consider all of the trade-offs.

Comment: Do you really need to keep all these in memory at the same time? 8Gb RAM consumption would mean that your program is a very special snowflake. Even the most advanced 3D games for PC consume less...

Comment: @Lundin Indeed. Probably an XY-problem

Comment: It is starting to look like a case for file-based merge sort.

Comment: Yes, I want to to keep all the numbers in memory

Comment: If you're input is a big file of integers stored in binary form with adequate endianess , why not using mmap to get a view map of the file and then sort & deduplicate with a stream workflow in another mmap ?

Comment: Eric's right: you don't want a list of integers at all, you want a set. And 2 billion bits is only 250 Mb.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a given number of values, and the range of those values is the same as the number of values, you can implement the list as an array where each array index represents a value and the value of each array element represents whether or not a given value is in the list.

For example:

```
char *arr = malloc(20000000001);
int i;

// populate list
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
for (i=0; i<20000000001; i++) {
    int value;
    scanf("%d", &value);
    arr[value] = 1;
}

// print list
for (i=0; i<20000000001; i++) {
    if (arr[i]) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Here we initialize the list to contain 0 for all values.  Then we read in the values.  If we read the value *n*, then we set `arr[n]` to 1.  This does two things: it inserts the value in the list and eliminates duplicates by always setting the value to 1 as opposed to incrementing the value.

This gives O(1) insersions with duplicate removal, and the list is already sorted.

Note also that since each element of the array only needs to store the values 0 or 1 we cause use `char` as the type to save memory.  We can further save memory if we use each *bit* to hold the value 0 or 1 for a given value.  Doing this will involve some bit shifting:

```
unsigned char *arr = malloc(20000000001 / 8 + 1);
int i;

// populate list
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
for (i=0; i<20000000001; i++) {
    int value;
    scanf("%d", &value);
    arr[value/8] |= 1 << (value%8);
}

// print list
for (i=0; i<20000000001; i++) {
    if (arr[i/8] & (1 << (i%8))) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

This cuts the memory requirements down to about 250MB which is still large but manageable.

Comment: Thanks for this. But elements of the array in your code are only 0 or 1. While there is a chance that the numbers are unique.

Comment: @SamuelJakes The values of the array elements just tell you if a number is in the list, i.e. if 100 is in the list then `arr[100]` will be set to 1.